# Storage Permission in Flutter

Tags: permissions, flutter

I am trying to get storage permission in the `initstate()` function of the class.I used two packages - `Simple_Permissions` and `Permission` package. But both give the same error to me.

FYI - I have put the permission in manifest already.

> "E/SimplePermission( 6405): set to never ask againandroid.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
>   I/SimplePermission( 6405): Requesting permission status : 4
>   I/flutter ( 6405): permission request result is PermissionStatus.deniedNeverAsk"

What I understood from this is that this error should come if the permission was set to "never ask again" by the user . But it is the first time I am requesting storage permission in my app .

What I have tried:

1. Uninstalling and reinstalling the app.
2. Using 2 different permission packages
3. Running app on different Android Versions, different emulators.

Also:

I request 2 permissions in my app, one for location and other for writing storage.

When I go to the **settings --> installed apps --> permissions -->** I CAN see the permission for location and I can turn it on/off. But I CANNOT see permission for storage.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue with multi_image_picker flutter package. Camera permission is granted OK, read storage granted OK, write storage is denied for no apparent reason, even though I tap Allow on everything. There must be something weird going on with Flutter and Write Storage permission.

Answer (score 4):

Have you added the below code to android manifest file?

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way to access storage using `permission_handler` package

```
dependencies:
  permission_handler: ^5.0.1
```

**Code Snippet**

status.isUndetermined is used to determine whether we had asked for permission yet or not.

```
          var status = await Permission.storage.status;
           if (status.isUndetermined) {
                // You can request multiple permissions at once.
                Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [
                  Permission.storage,
                  Permission.camera,
                ].request();
                print(statuses[Permission.storage]); // it should print PermissionStatus.granted
              }
```

**Note:** Don't forget to add permission in AndroidMenifest for android & info.plist for iOS.

Comment: What is the storage permission for iOS in the Info.plist?

Comment: please mention using / import library,

Answer (score 3):

This may be happening because another plugin is setting android:maxSdkVersion attribute on your WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE declaration in the AndroidManifest.xml Try replacing the line in AndroidManifest.xml with:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion"/>
```

This fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Don't forget to add `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` in `<manifest>` attribute