# Which permission are necessary to read and write a file on internal storage on an ios/android device/emulator?

Tags: android, ios

I need to write and read a file on ios and android internal storage and iam not sure which permissions i have to set in the podfile/info.plist?

Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54322030/storage-permission-in-flutter

Answer (score 0):

For Android you need to update `AndroidManifest.xml` file and add :

```
<manifest>
  ...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application>
        ...
```

And for IOS there is no permission required. For more info to write file to secondary storage look at [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:).